# Python Robot Framework Pass arguments to a function

Tags: python, robotframework

I try to use this method

```
def my_click(self, locator, info="click on button error", timeout=5):
    element = self.wait_for_visibility(locator, info, timeout)
    element.click()

def wait_for_visibility(self, locator, info="no error", timeout=10):
    return WebDriverWait(self.get_driver(), timeout).until(
        expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(locator), info)
```

inside robot framework file

```
Register Proper Data
    [Setup]    Open Browser ${web-page}    browser=${browser}
    my click  (By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "register")
```

but the program returns:

> TypeError: find_element() takes at most 3 arguments (35 given) - which
>   is the number of letters in the argument

Why is it happening? How to pass arguments to a keyword?

Answer (score 2):

Why *my click* argument is in brackets? It should be without brackets and comma. Something like:

```
my click    By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT    register
```

Please ensure that there are 3-4 spaces between the function and the variables and each variable.

Comment: still the same error, I was using this function with python+selenium and it was working this way, maybe something else should be added to make it recognize the whole argument?

Comment: Jędrek, please check answer updated by A.Kootstra. Also try to call your keyword from RIDE. It will eliminate wrong amount of spaces/tabs.